# How to save an EC2 instance freely

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to save an EC2 instance for free? I understand that stopping and then starting the instance is chargeable.

Is there any way around it so that i dont have to create a new instance everytime and install the required packages agian?

Comment: Stopping and starting in and of themselves do not cause charges.  Charges accumulate when your instance is on or if you've got an EBS volume sitting around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the instance is in a stopped state, then all you will be charged for is the size of the EBS volumes you have provisioned. The only way to get around this is to not store anything at all. Even if you turn your instance into an AMI, you will still be charged for the storage space the AMI takes up.